# Run MEAN stack on SSL

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I want to host my site on **https** instead of **http**. I am using **AngularJs** for my Front End and **NodeJs** for my Back-end. I will be using https://letsencrypt.org/ for SSL certificate.

I am not able to find a way to run both web-servers on https.

Note: I do not want to separate front-end from back-end by urls.

I hope i made my point clear.

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: AngularJS is not a web server. Your SSL configuration will be done in Node.

Comment: Just node apis will be used in angular code.SSL certificates will be added to nodejs code.

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe we need to run angularjs as well as nodejs on https as otherwise we might have problems with browsers security policies

Comment: @JorgeValle Yes AngularJS itself is not a web server.

Comment: @VedanshAgrawal what you have to do is keep your angularjs files in a server and nodejs files also.In server code of nodejs you need to use ssl certificates.And next whatever the apis you create with node those apis will be used in angular code.You can just call your angular file with domain name.Like  https:// https://example.com/login Here **login**  is nothing but login.html file in that file you will use apis of nodejs which are in http://example.com/...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "Unclear what you are asking", not because it's unclear what you are trying to do, but because it's unclear what kind of help you need, or what you've tried so far.  "I am not able to find a way to run both web-servers on https." isn't really a question, it's a statement that you don't know what to do, which is really too broad.  Besides that, it's not really clear why you have two web servers here;  AngularJs doesn't need a web server, beyond the master server serving it's static HTML and scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I am presenting a simple application i.e.,both angularjs and nodejs works on https.First of all keep this application in server(entire folder) . Second create a **public** folder and place this `index.html` file in it.Here is the code for it

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="app.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body ng-app="myApp">
     <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <form>
        Author:
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.author">
        <br>
        <br> Title:
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.title">
        <br>
        <br> Body:
        <input type="author" ng-model="data.body">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit()">
      </form>
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

and here is the **angular code** save the file as `app.js` in **public** folder.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
 $scope.data = {};
$scope.submit= function(){
    console.log('clicked submit');
    $http({
        url: 'https://localhost:3443/blah',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $scope.data
    }).then(function (httpResponse) {
        console.log('response:', httpResponse);
    })
   }
 });
```

You need to have `angular.min.js` file .Keep this file in **public** folder. I don't know much more about this file.Basically I am from backend side.What I understood about this is without this file we can't able to load angular code. So here is the link of the file https://github.com/Syedayesha/MEAN-Stack/blob/master/public/angular.min.js .

Next **server code** save the file as `server.js`.Keep this file in root folder.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
var fs=require('fs');
var http=require('http');
var https=require('https');
    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
    app.use(express.static('public'));
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'testn'
   });
   connection.connect();
var options = {
 key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
 cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
}
    app.post('/blah', function(req, res, next) {
    var cope = req.body;
    console.log('request received:', req.body);
   var query = connection.query('insert into form set ?', cope, function (err,     result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.send(err);
    } else {
        return res.send('Ok');
    }
    });
    //res.send('received the data.');
    });
    var server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
var server1 = https.createServer(options,app).listen(3443);
console.log('server running on 3443');
```

Here I connected with `mysqldb`. you need to give your domain ssl certificates in near **options** variable in `server.js`. You need to have ssl certificates in root folder. You can download entire project from my github . Here is the link https://github.com/Syedayesha/MEAN-Stack.

Run the node server using `node server.js` and open the browser and enter `https://localhost:3443/index.html` . That's it !!! you will get the `index.html` file and enter the data and check that data is stored in db or not. Actually I am working with xampp so I am using apache server. So that I run the url as localhost. You can run the url using your site name **example** `https://example.com:3443/index.html`. And you need to change the `url` in **angular code** `app.js` as `https://example.com:3443/blah`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should put your Node service behind a reverse proxy like Apache or Nginx, and use the ProxyPass (Apache) or proxy_pass (Nginx) directives to send traffic to your Node service. Then you can use Certbot to configure HTTPS for your Apache or Nginx instance, and you don't need to configure HTTPS for your Node service (so long as it runs on the same host).

Besides making it easier to set up HTTPS, using a reverse proxy is better than using Node directly, because you can easily add additional Node processes to take better advantage of all of your CPUs.